# Remove u' infront of my JSON data

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm new to python and it seems that all my JSON data is combined with u' prefix as such:

```
{u'number': u'12345666', u"items"...}
```

I don't need this data (unicode or whatever) as I want to print the **string** into a Javascript variable:

```
var obj = data; // data is the object above.
```

My python looks something like this;

```
index.html:
var obj = ${data};
```

I'm using the moko framework for templating.

```
// getitems() return {'number':'12312...}
context = {'data': getitems(self)}
self.render_response('index.html',**context)
```

The processed javascript output data look like this:

```
var obj = {u'number': u'12345666', u"items"...}
```

This is my problem.

Comment: You are confusing JSON with printing a dictionary.

Comment: You do not want to remove the `u''`, it is only an indication that you are looking at unicode strings. Your templating code will take care of JSON, provided you *encode to JSON* first.

Comment: +1: Simply because I don't know why this question has so many downvotes?

Comment: @freakish I don't understand it to. They expect everyone to be an expect and people new are simple down voted.

Comment: What is the meaning of "w/e"?

Comment: @Robᵩ  whatever shorthand. Not professional i know.

Comment: @freakish - I expect that the downvotes are due to the missing question. OP makes *statements*, and describes a *problem*, but fails to *ask a question*.

Comment: @CezarisLT - I don't care about professionalism, I care about communication. In this instance, I had no idea what you were talking about. (Ditto for "tempting" and "procced". I had to guess at your meanings there.)

Comment: @Robᵩ That's true, however the question is obvious from the context. A little to harsh in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting a dictionary to a string (probably Mako does `str(...)` for you). But you should **jsonify** it, i.e.

```
import json
context = { 'data': json.dumps(getitems(self)) }
```

Comment: Thank you, need people like you on this site.

Comment: Is there a clean javascript solution? I'm having the same problem but I'm using an external API to get the data. I have no access to its code so I need to solve this in the javascript frontend.

Comment: @FrancisA No, you would need a Python parser or at least a part of it. There's no such tool for JS AFAIK.